Safety - Using equipment rated for a mains voltage of 115 V with autotransformers in a 230 V environment
In practical use - think of touring musicians - equipment designed for a mains voltage of 115 V may end up being used with autotransformers (non-isolated!) on 230 V outlets. In these cases, it may not be known if the output poles of the autotransformers are at 0 V and 115 V (referred to the local ground, N/PE) or maybe at 115 V and 230 V, having the connected device floating at the local mains voltage while still providing the correct input voltage across its "L" and "N" terminals.
It may then happen that the internal insulation is subjected to twice the voltage it was designed for. I have checked some standards, and indeed, less clearance and creepage is required for the smaller working voltages found in 115 V equipment compared to 230 V equipment. The same goes for the test voltages needed when building transformers. I have checked standards like EN 60950 and 61558.
In practical use, most equipment might still be built to withstand any common mains voltage anywhere in the world (100 V up to 240 V). However, exceptions may be around - especially for devices with no mains voltage selectors and transformers built for 115 V or 120 V use only.
Are there certification marks (UL, CE), together with certain standards (for home/office/audio equipment) that could be found on a cabinet's back panel and that would tell the users they are still good to go when combining a 115 V or 120 V device with an autotransformer (non-isolated) on a 230 V mains outlet, because the standard would require the same safety features for "anything mains" (100 V to 240 V) to "anything accessible by the user" (SELV/PELV)?
Are there exceptions where a "true" (isolated) step-down transformer should absoluteley be used? (However, an internal, insulated power supply is always assumed in the context of this question. Just maybe one that was built to be used in a 115 V or 120 V environment only. Things like ancient tube equipment with the entire chassis connected to mains is beyond the scope of this question.)
(Note: This question is on the topic of applying electrical devices. However, the details needed to answer this questions dive into knowledge needed when designing these devices, so I believe it is on-topic here.)

Transformers designed for use on building sites are available - 3kW and made specially.

Even 120 V equipment should be built to withstand the 1500 V transients that routinely occur on domestic wiring from local load fluctuations and remote lightning strikes.

@Neil_UK I agree that for most practical purposes, no one is likely to get killed - but when I look at EN 60950, for example, an AC supply circuit of up to 150 V (footnote: including 120/208 V and 120/240 V, i.e. live-to-neutral max. 150 V) shall take 1500 V surges (for OVC II), while a supply circuit of up to 300 V (including 230/400V systems) shall take 2500 V surges. So higher surges are assumed for higher AC supply voltages, and 115 V transformers may (will?) be tested with lower voltages than 230 V transformers, and may (will?) have weaker isolation properties?

If the equipment has an earth, I would expect both it and the neutral to be maintained through the autotransformer. If it doesn't, there's nothing to worry about creepage to. I don't see an issue either way.
